# Doctrine 2 command line configuration as an external lib

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I try to configure Doctrine 2 as an external lib for my project.
So, I installed it by Composer, and followed the instructions on Doctrine documentation. And command line does'nt work.

Here is the part on Doctrine in my Bootstrap :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

/* Instantiation of doctrine
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

$paths = array(__DIR__."/Application/Entity");
$isDevMode = true;

// the connection configuration
$dbParams = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents('Application/Config/Private/bdd.yml'));

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode);
$em = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Here is the content of my cli-config.php file (in the project root):

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner;

require_once 'index.php'; // my bootstrap



return ConsoleRunner::createHelperSet($em);
```

So, now, the documentation say that I can use Doctrine in console mode by typing : `php vendor/bin/doctrine`
But, when I use this command, it don't execute. I just have the content of doctrine file :

```
dir=$(d=${0%[/\\]*}; cd "$d"; cd "../doctrine/orm/bin" && pwd)

# See if we are running in Cygwin by checking for cygpath program
if command -v 'cygpath' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        # Cygwin paths start with /cygdrive/ which will break windows PHP,
        # so we need to translate the dir path to windows format. However
        # we could be using cygwin PHP which does not require this, so we
        # test if the path to PHP starts with /cygdrive/ rather than /usr/bin
        if [[ $(which php) == /cygdrive/* ]]; then
                dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
        fi
fi

dir=$(echo $dir | sed 's/ /\ /g')
"${dir}/doctrine" "$@"
```

php work fine, and I tried to install a symfony project (to test command line) and command line work with Symfony. So, I think that the problem come from installation / configuration of Doctrine.

I don't know what I missed, but I can't use Doctrine by command line. Is anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command for doctrine you're calling is not a PHP file, but rather a shell script.

Call `./vendor/bin/doctrine` instead, and it should work as expected.

Comment: I'm on windows. If I try whith "Bash Ubuntu on windows" it works (Tanks it's already a big step). But how can I do to make it work on windows command line ?

Comment: You could call `php vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine.php` or `sh vendor/bin/doctrine`

Comment: Thanks it's just that I needed. :)